# Let $G$ be a group and let $H \subseteq G$ be a finite subset that satisfies properties (H0) and (H1). Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

(H0) = set $H$ is non empty. 
(H1) = if $a,b \in H$, then $ab \in H$

The only property I need to proof that $H$ is a subgroup is (H2) = if $a \in H$, then $a^{-1} \in H$.

This however is where I do not see the connection.

Given that $H$ is a subset of $G$ I do not see the reasoning that when an element out of $G$ is copied in the set $H$ that also the inverse (of that element) has to be added to $H$.

Also the excerise mentioned **Note: the example $\mathbb{Z_{\geq 0}} \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ shows that the finiteness of H is essential!**

Due to this and the emphasison the word finite in the excerise I assume that this plays a big part in the proof, but again, I do not see the connection. The only thing I am pretty sure of, is that since $H$ is non empty the identity element of $G$ is in $H$.

Comment: Let's try to motivate your thinking to come up with the answer below.  All you know at the start is that $H$ has at least one element $a$.  What other elements, then, must also be in $H$?  What additional conclusion can you draw from the fact that $H$ is finite?

Comment: We know one element $a \in H$, if we assume $a \neq e$, then we know that $a,e \in H$. This satisfies (H1) ($ea = ae = e \in H$). But again this seems to be a correct subset of $G$, without being a subgroup of $G$

Comment: Using $a$ and $H_1$, can you generate any other elements that have to be in $H$?

Comment: Given that $a \neq e$ and $a,e \in H$. Then I do not violate (H1), because $ea = a \in H$ and $ae = a \in H$. These two elements are part of $G$ and so $H$ is a subset of $G$ (but again still not a subgroup, because the inverse of $a$ is missing). I am unsure what I am missing.

Comment: What do you know about $a^2$?  For that matter, what do you know about $a^n$, for $n \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Do you mean that assuming  that $a \in H$ then $aa = a^2 \in H$ by proprety (H1). if so, I do understand that principle now, which we can extend to if $a \in H$ then $a^n \in H$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by property (H1). Even with this new insight, I am unable to conclude that the inverse of each element is also in $H$.

Comment: This is where you need the fact that $H$ is finite.  You have an infinite list of elements that all lie within some finite set.  What can you say?

Comment: The set $H$ will have to 'loop' to be finite. Because of this, there should be an element for which $a, b \in H$ $ab = e$ to ensure the loop. After doing some examples I can see the pattern now. Assuming $H = \{e,a,a^2 ,a^3\} \subset \{e, a, a^2, a^3, ...\}$, when (H0) and (H1) are satisfied we get that for $xa^3 = e$ for which we know that $a^{-3}a^3 = e$, so $a^{-3} \in H$. By applying (H1) on $a^{-3}$ we also have that $a^{-1}, a^{-2} \in H$, thus the inverses are in $H$. To have a formal proof should I replace $a^{3}$ with $a^{n-1}$?  Thank you very much for guiding me.

Comment: Almost.  What you know is that for some $0 \lt m \lt n, a^m=a^n$.  You don't (yet) know that $a$ is a repeated element; it could conceivably be the case that some of the powers of $a$ never repeat (though you'll end up proving that can't be the case).  But that tells you $a^{n-m}=e \in H$ with $n-m \geq 1$.  If $n-m=1$, then $a=e=a^{-1} \in H$.  If $n-m \gt 1$, then $a^{n-m-1}=a^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Let $a \in H$, and consider the set $A = \{a, a^2, a^3, a^4, \ldots\}$.

Since $H$ is finite, what can you say about $A$ (use the pigeonhole principle!)? Can you use this to conclude that $a^{-1} \in H$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: You beat me to it! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Take $a \in H$. Condition H1 implies that the restriction to $H$ of the map $x \mapsto ax$ is a map $H \to H$. Since $G$ is a group, this map is injective. Since $H$ is finite, the map is surjective. Thus, there is $f \in H$ such that $af=a$, that is, $f=e$. Then there is $b \in H$ such that $ab=e$, that is, $b=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in H$ by $(H_1)$, $a^n\in H$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $H$ is finite then  $\exists n_a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{n_a}=1$ and of course $a^{n_a-1} \in H$ .That suggests that $1\in H$ and $a^{-1} =a^{n_a-1}\in H$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in H$. This exists due to (H0).

If $a=e$, then $a^{-1}=a\in H$.

If $a\neq e$, then consider all the powers of $a$, which must be in $H$ by closure (*i.e.*, (H1)). Since $H$ is finite, by the pigeonhole principle, some of these powers coincide.

Can you continue from here?

> **Hint:** See Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition),"* page 64, Theorem 3.3.